# How to modify link based on unique div ID once per ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of `div`s with the class `.tile`. Each `div` in the `.tile` class has a unique ID. I would like to create an array (of ID's) and modify `a.link` based on the `ID`. I would like to modify `a.link` once per `.tile ID`. Where should I go from here?

```
<div class="tile" id="1asdfasdfa"></div>
<div class="tile" id="2fdasdfaas"></div>
<div class="tile" id="3dfasdsadf"></div>
<div class="tile" id="4fghdfghdf"></div>
<div class="tile" id="5sdfasfdaa"></div>
<div class="tile" id="6dfasdfasf"></div>
...
<div class="tile" id="100sdfasff"></div>

<a href="#" class="link">Im A Link</a>
```

One link - changed on random interval X. Going sequentially through an array. Or some list of ID's. I thought `.each()` would go through each ID and modify the link once per.

```
$('html, body').scrollTop( $(document).height() );

setTimeout(function() {

    var numItems = $('.tile').length;

 $('.tile').each(function(index) {
    var tileID = $(this).attr('id');    //Thank you 
    var ranNum = ((Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 3))*1000);
    console.log(index);
   $("#"+tileID).each(function () {

        setInterval(function() {        
        $("a.link").attr("href", "/listing/share?post_id="+tileID);
        }, ranNum);

   });

});   

    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Why would someone down vote this question?

Comment: To add to the problem. It seems to index 5-6 of the id's (as reflected by the a.link changes) although the console logs show the full list.

Comment: since you're using jQuery, `this` has to be used like `$(this)`

Comment: @JosanIracheta I get syntax errors when I run it that way... not sure why

Comment: I'm not following exactly what you want to do here honestly, which probably accounts for the downvote. You want to create an array of what? What do you want to modify the links to? Are you saying your code doesn't work?

Comment: PS. The HTML would probably help a lot here.

Comment: @JosanIracheta thank you. I see what you mean now :)

Comment: @RickCalder Its up now

Comment: Okay, getting closer. Do you want a list of links, or are you just trying to change that one link on a random timer?

Comment: @RickCalder Just the one at random. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Cool, my answer should do it then, works fine in the fiddle I linked.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of all the ids.
Then inside setInterval you choose a random number between 0 and the length of that array, then set your linkId to the value of the ids array at the random number. Then set your href based on that linkId.

This works because it doesn't matter how many divs you have, it will just push new div ids to the ids array.

```
var ids = [];

$(".tile").each( function( index, item ) {
    ids.push($(item).attr("id"));
});

var counter = 0;    
var ranNum = ((Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 3))*1000);
setInterval( function() {
  var linkId = ids[counter];
  $("a.link").attr("href", "/listing/share?post_id=" + linkId).text(linkId);
  counter == ids.length - 1 ? counter = 0 : counter++;
  ranNum = ((Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 3))*1000);
}, ranNum)
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tf112w70/2/

Comment: Thats not quite what Im looking for. I need the id to be followed sequentially, not at random. Only the interval is random.

Comment: Fixed, sorry missed what was random